# How can you set a variable as the output of a command and then use that variable later in the same command on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, terminal, command

I want to have a single command, not a script, that I can use to define a variable as a command output and then put that output into other commands. My best guess as to what that would look like is this:

`LIST=$(ls) | head -1 | echo "${LIST}"`

One reason that I want to do this is so that I can create a command that can find the pid of a program and then kill that pid. My best try doing that is:

`DiscPid=$(ps -e | grep Discord | cut -b 1-5 | head -1 \ ) | kill "${DiscPid}"`

But I'm not able to get this to work

I'm still relatively new to Linux and Bash so any help would be appreciated

Comment: or `killall Discord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a semicolon after setting the variable: `var=foo; echo $var`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need piping here

```
DiscPid=$(code) | kill "${DiscPid}"
```

Change '|' to ';' and this one '\' also spare

```
DiscPid=$(ps -e | grep Discord | cut -b 1-5 | head -1); kill "${DiscPid}"
```